# Removing css information from HTML in java

Tags: java, html, parsing

Is there any library or pre-written code to remove css attributes from HTML code.

The requirement is, the Java code has to parse through the input html document, and remove the css attributes and produce the output html document.

For example if the input html document has this element,

```
      <p class="abc" style="xyz" > some text </p>
```

the output should be

```
      <p > some text </p>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use jsoup and NodeTraversor to remove class and style attributes from all elements

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input);


NodeTraversor traversor  = new NodeTraversor(new NodeVisitor() {

  @Override
  public void tail(Node node, int depth) {
    if (node instanceof Element) {
        Element e = (Element) node;
        e.removeAttr("class");
        e.removeAttr("style");
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void head(Node node, int depth) {        
  }
});

traversor.traverse(doc.body());
String modifiedHtml = doc.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Cyberneko](http://nekohtml.sourceforge.net/) to parse the document and add a simple [filter](http://nekohtml.sourceforge.net/filters.html) that looks something like this:

```
public class RemoveStyleFilter
    extends DefaultFilter
{
  @Override
  public void startElement(QName element, XMLAttributes attributes, Augmentations augs)
    throws XNIException
  {
    for (String forbidden : new String[] {"class", "style"})
    {
      int index = attributes.getIndex(forbidden);
      if (index >= 0)
      {
        attributes.removeAttributeAt(index);
      }
    }
    super.startElement(element, attributes, augs);
  }
}
```