# Format multipart HTML/text e-mail to work in Internet Explorer

Tags: java, html, internet-explorer, layout, jakarta-mail

I made an application using JavaMail which reads e-mail and takes its [content](http://pastebin.com/XYCM277w). The content will be fetched in HTML. This content will be analyzed and then forwarded to another e-mail address.

I've tested the e-mail's layout in Chrome, Mozilla, Outlook, Office 365, Thunderbird and Internet Explorer. Everything works well, except, of course, IE.

I made some screenshots, one in Chrome and the other in Internet Explorer, both from the same mail client (Office 365).

#### Good email in Chrome

[image: Chrome E-mail]

#### Misformed IE E-mail

[image: Misformed IE E-mail]

I put together a `multipart` e-mail, a part for the content and one for attachments. This is the code I am using:

```
public void SentTest(String messageContent) throws IOException, ParseException, NoSuchProviderException {

            //Only get text between HTML tags
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*?<html.*?>(.*?)</html>.*?");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(messageContent);
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            messageContent= matcher.group(1);
        }

        messageContent= Jsoup.clean(messageContent, Whitelist.relaxed());

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smpt.host", "pod51010.outlook.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
        try {
            transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
            try {
                transport.connect("host", "email", "password");
            } catch (MessagingException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (NoSuchProviderException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {

            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("email"));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    InternetAddress.parse("testemail"));
            message.setSubject("Test");
            MimeBodyPart testMessagePart = new MimeBodyPart();
            testMessagePart.setText(inhoudBericht, "ISO-8859-1", "html");

            testMessagePart.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"");
            testMessagePart.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "quoted-printable");
            testMessagePart.setHeader("MIME-Version", "1.0");


            Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("multipart");
            multipart.addBodyPart(testMessagePart);

            //Set the content of the Message
            message.setHeader("", "");
            message.setContent(multipart, "html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"");

            try {
                transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            transport.close();

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }


    }
```

My question is: how do I make the layout of the e-mail flexible so it will work in all browsers?

#### Edit

After adding `<html>` tags and a `Doctype` and removing `width` attributes from the HTML, the layout gets displayed "correctly", but of course there's another problem:

[image: Blue layout]

As you can see it is now blue and the table outlines are showing. Any idea to get rid of this?

#### Edit

Got rid of the blue background by removing the `bgcolor` tags. Now the only problem is to remove the table outlines.

Comment: Well, browsers are different... Also, please note, you will have to check for the quirks in the mail clients too - for example Outlook has quite some "specialties" as to what it likes, and what it does not...

Also, the code you posted is not relevant - the content itself is what makes a difference. Post that, and someone with experience on this topic can spot the problem. I'd advise you to use the simplest approach possible: no flexibility, everything fixed height and width, no fancy CSS, and basically: the basic of the basic... And even with that, you can have some unpleasant surprises...

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I forgot to add in my question that both screenshots are from the same client (Office 365), just in different browsers.

Comment: What does the HTML look like?

Comment: Oh, I missed the fact that the content is not something you create. Then you can't really do much... The exact issue seems to be some kind of HTML table related quirk. Maybe I'd give a try to cleanse the source HTML from any css - but that might result in wrong layouts, maybe at least equally wrong on all browsers, that is...

Comment: @MathiasSchwarz uploaded it to pastebin: http://pastebin.com/XYCM277w this is the HTML content which is fetched from an e-mail with JavaMail. I didn't change anything, except I removed the headers since they were showing as e-mail content.

Comment: Weird. The HTML is actually valid, but it is a mess though

Comment: @MathiasSchwarz I've added HTML tags around the original HTML and removed some information from the nodes. See my edited question.

Comment: @ppeterka I tried removing css information with the code provided with this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8180459/975468, it did something but not quite as I expected, please see my edited question.

Comment: to remove the borders: try adding <table border="0">, or do this with css: border: 0;

Comment: @HansVn Thanks for your comment, but just solved it by using Jsoup's NodeTraversor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by using Jsoup and NodeTraverser (credits to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8180459/975468) answer)

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input);


NodeTraversor traversor  = new NodeTraversor(new NodeVisitor() {

  @Override
  public void tail(Node node, int depth) {
    if (node instanceof Element) {
        Element e = (Element) node;
        e.removeAttr("width");
        e.removeAttr("border");
        e.removeAttr("bgcolor");
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void head(Node node, int depth) {        
  }
});

traversor.traverse(doc.body());
String modifiedHtml = doc.toString();
```

And adding a doctype

`modifiedHTML = "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \" //W3C//DTD HTML 4.0.1//en\">"+modifiedHTML;`

It's probably not the best solution, but it works and I am happy with that :). Thanks for the help!