# Html.fromHtml(String).toString(); gives css in starting String

Tags: android

```
protected String getEntryContent(String entryContent) {
    Log.d(getClass().getName(), "getEntryContent()");
    String mWebViewContent;
     mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(baseUrl,
            entryContent, mimeType,
            encoding, null);

        mWebViewContent =Html.fromHtml(entryContent).toString();
        return mWebViewContent;
    }
```

Output:

```
    h2 {font-size:1.2em;font-weight:normal;} a {color:#6688cc;} ol {padding-             left:1.5em;} blockquote {margin-left:0em;} .interProject, .noprint {display:none;} li, blockquote {margin-top:0.5em;margin-bottom:0.5em;}


quarterly (not comparable) Occurring once every quarter year (three months).

quarterly rent payments
```

This gives me starting  line as a CSS.
How can i remove that?

Answer (score 2):

You probably passed the inline CSS in your string. From the javadoc of `HTML.fromHtml` it nowhere states that it can handle inline css, therefore it propably handles it like normal text

> Returns displayable styled text from the provided HTML string. Any  tags in the HTML will use the specified ImageGetter to request a representation of the image (use null if you don't want this) and the specified TagHandler to handle unknown tags (specify null if you don't want this).

You have to remove the css manually yourself. See this answer on how to do that: [Removing css information from HTML in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8180171/removing-css-information-from-html-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
CharSequence mSequence = Html.fromHtml("<b>Hello</b> Android");
    textView.setText(mSequence);
```

You can also convert it into String as:

```
String mString = mSequence.toString();
```

Comment: It's not working.
I want only
    quarterly (not comparable) Occurring once every quarter year (three months).

    quarterly rent payments


String entryContent is my parsedText from JSON to String

Comment: It's not working.
I want only
    quarterly (not comparable) Occurring once every quarter year (three months).

    quarterly rent payments.

`\n`
String entryContent is my parsedText HttpResponse to JSON and JSON to String.